# ConstraintLayout: Unable to scale image to fit a ratio in ListView

Tags: android

• I have a ListView.

• Within in I have custom items/views.

• Each item is defined as a ConstraintLayout where there has two ImageView which is supposed to have a constant aspect ratio. Two ImageView are horizontally distributed on the screen。

But somehow the images are not maintaining the aspect ratio.

Here are the xml files, screenshot and code to create the ListView view:

item_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/image2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_title" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.qcymall.demotest.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#ff778899"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listview)
    val datas = ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>>()
    val data = HashMap<String, Any>()
    data.put("title", "Hello")
    datas.add(data)
    val adapter = SimpleAdapter(this, datas, R.layout.item_content, arrayOf("title"), intArrayOf(R.id.item_title))
    listView.setAdapter(adapter)
  }
}
```

screenshot:

[image: screenShot1]

When I modify the “android:layout_width=0dp" as "android:layout_width=100dp", I can display it normally, like this screenshot.

[image: screenShot2]

Comment: So do you want to show the two images divided equally not having the margin from left and right, like what you have shown in the screen shot??

Comment: I think you can use Guideline in constraint view to have a constant aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, It's like the same effect in the activity_main layout.